# Nodejs Convert text to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason I'm having such a hard time converting this txt file to an actual javascript array.

**myJson.txt**

```
{"action": "key press", "timestamp": 1523783621, "user": "neovim"}
{"action": "unlike", "timestamp": 1523784584, "user": "r00k"}
{"action": "touch", "timestamp": 1523784963, "user": "eevee"}
{"action": "report as spam", "timestamp": 1523786005, "user": "moxie"}
```

Currently what I have that doesn't work

```
const fs = require('fs');

function convert(input_file_path) {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(input_file_path, 'utf8');
    const newFormat = file
      .replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,'')
      .replace(/}{/g, '},{');

    console.log([JSON.parse(newFormat)]);
}

convert('myJson.txt');
```

Comment: can't you loop through it and save it in format of [key: value, key: value,...]

Comment: What is your expected result? `[{ action: ...}, { action: ...}]`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Yes please. I'm so frustrated with this it's killing me..lol

Comment: Is it maybe because the input data is not in array form?

Comment: The curly brackets indicate an object, you're looking at arrays, two different data types. (Arrays use square brackets)

Comment: @JacobSchneider Yeah I know, that's why I tried to wrap it with [] lol. Like my last option is to append the brackets in the beginning of the array and ending. And then parse it after that?

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you restate your question?

Comment: That looks like valid new line delimited json see: http://ndjson.org/ for libraries that handle it.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Yes I have! Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome! cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your file contains a JSON object per line, you could read that file line by line, using `readline`.

Each line is then parsed, and push into an array, which is then returned (resolved) after the file is fully read.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

function convert(file) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        // Handle stream error (IE: file not found)
        stream.on('error', reject);

        const reader = readline.createInterface({
            input: stream
        });

        const array = [];

        reader.on('line', line => {
            array.push(JSON.parse(line));
        });

        reader.on('close', () => resolve(array));
    });
}


convert('myJson.txt')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have done this in this way

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var array = [];
var input = null;
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/demo.txt')
    
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    array.push(JSON.parse(line));
});
rd.on('close', function(d){
  array.forEach(e=>console.log(e.action))
})
```

What's happening here is, I am reading the lines of the file on by one using `readline` which is one of the core modules of `nodejs`. Listening on the events and doing what needed.

And yeah, you'll have to parse the line to `JSON` for sure ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to parse JS array as JSON array. while JSON array string should be only string.

Here what you're trying to do:

```
jsArray = ['{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo":"baz"}']
```

This is a valid JS array of a single string value '{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo":"baz"}'.

while

```
jsonArrayStr = '["{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo":"baz"}"]'
```

This is a valid JSON array string (as the square brackets is part of the string).

So as to get your code running, you need to add the square brackets to your string before parsing it.

```
function convert(input_file_path) {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(input_file_path, 'utf8');
    const newFormat = file
      .replace("{", "[{")
      .replace(/}$/, "}]")

    console.log(JSON.parse('[' + newFormat + ']'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing in the script is reading the content of text file line by line and storing it to array along with converting it to JSON object. When we reach last line and our JSON array/object has all the data. Now you can write this object to a new file `fs.writeFileSync()` after converting JSON object to string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Note :- You've to install Line reader package i.e. `npm install line-reader`

```
var lineReader = require('line-reader');
var fs = require('fs')

var jsonObj = {};
var obj = [];
var file = "fileName.json"
var num= 0;

lineRead();
async function lineRead(){
lineReader.eachLine('input.txt', function(line, last) {
// to check on which line we're.
      console.log(num);
      num++;
      convertJson(line)

      if(last){
//when it's last line we convert json obj to string and save it to new file.
        var data = JSON.stringify(obj)
        fs.writeFileSync(file,data);

      }
});
}

function convertJson(data){
        var currentVal = data
        var value = JSON.parse(data)
        var temp = value;
//storing the value in json object
        jsonObj = value;
        obj.push(jsonObj);
    }
  
}
```