# txt file to json using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I have a simple txt file with data in this format with millions of lines:

```
{"a":9876312,"b":1572568981512}
{"a":9876312,"b":1572568981542}
```

I want to convert this into a file with "dot" json extension file using reduce function in NodeJs and return statement, probably looking like this:

```
[{"a":9876312,"b":1572568981512},
{"a":9876312,"b":1572568981542}]
```

Any help will be really really appreciated. Thanks :)

SO far I tried this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const FILE_NAME = 'abc.txt';
const x = mapEvents(getJSONFileData(FILE_NAME));

function getJSONFileData(filename) {
   return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')
   .split('\n')
   .map(JSON.parse)
}

function mapEvents(events) {
events.reduce((acc, data) => {
  return [{data.a, data.b}]
});
}

console.log(x)
```

I am getting an 'undefined' value constantly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs Convert text to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713174/nodejs-convert-text-to-json)

Comment: i am getting an error with it.. but i was hoping to do it with reduce function and return statement.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: unexpected token , in JSON

Comment: Print the `line` where you're getting the error, because the error is telling you that one of those lines is not a JSON.

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: @AniketG: I added my code to the question. You can see what i am trying to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some issues, in your code.

1. You haven't returned anything from mapEvents function, that makes your varaible x value undefined.
2. getJSONFileData needs some fixing.

You can use below code:-

```
const fs = require('fs');
const FILE_NAME = 'abc.txt';
const x = mapEvents(getJSONFileData(FILE_NAME));

function getJSONFileData(filename) {
  return fs
    .readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(JSON.parse);
}

function mapEvents(events) {
  return JSON.stringify(events);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: When implementing your code i noticed that, If i have a number like '4611687012137402260' in the code.. it is getting turned into '4611687012137402000'.. because it is being treated as a number.. any way to overcome that?

Comment: @thealchemist this issue is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869275/json-not-converting-long-numbers-appropriately

Comment: const fs = require("fs");
const FILE_NAME = "abc.txt";
const x = mapEvents(getJSONFileData(FILE_NAME));

function getJSONFileData(filename) {
  return fs
    .readFileSync(filename, "utf-8")
    .split("\n")
    .filter(Boolean);
}

function mapEvents(events) {
  return JSON.stringify(events).replace(/\\|"/g, "");
}

console.log(x);

Comment: @thealchemist you can use above code to fix this issue.

Comment: That actually converts the entire json array into one string.. its not a valid json anymore.. :/

Comment: const fs = require("fs");
const FILE_NAME = "abc.txt";
const x = mapEvents(getJSONFileData(FILE_NAME));

function getJSONFileData(filename) {
  return fs
    .readFileSync(filename, "utf-8")
    .split("\n")
    .filter(Boolean);
}

function mapEvents(events) {
  return events.map(item =>
    JSON.parse(
      item
        .replace(/":/g, `":"`)
        .replace(/,"/g, `","`)
        .replace(/}/, `"}`)
    )
  );
}

console.log(x);

Comment: @thealchemist try this, it will convert number to string from the array item.